# Можно ли создать программу для Android и привязать к USSD?

Tags: мобильная-разработка, android

Привет всем.

Хочу создать программу на Андроид и привязать USSD команду к ней. Представляю себе так: открываю программу, там ТЕГ, например, (Баланс или проверка номера и прочие услуги). Я нажимаю на баланс и при помощи USSD, кода, например, *210# показывает мой баланс (Просто клик на тег Баланс, допустим, ----> автоматом перебрасывает на определенную USSD команду).

Почему хочу сделать? - Потому что в мобильных компаниях полно прочих услуг, хочу в каждый тег прописать USSD команду и проверять и баланс, и подключать платные услуги. Это делаю, для того чтобы упростить мобильные бизнес-процессы и не вспоминать каждую USSD команду для проверки баланса и т.д.

У кого какие идеи есть, поделитесь советом.

Comment: @fir4ik_92, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Хотите сделать вот такую программу [Check Balance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.drjunior.checkbalance)?

Answer (score 1):

Может,это поможет   [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/234425/).